# How do I achieve swipe left/right with feedback in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to swipe right to "accept" and swipe left to "refuse" with some visible feedback just like shown below

[swipe right example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtVF7.jpg)

[swipe left example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDETN.jpg)

how do I do that on a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Flutter Slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable) package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete guide: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible

1. Create a list.
2. Wrap each item in `Dismissible`.
3. Create buttons that would show behind.